# Starting an exe file with parameters on a remote PC

Tags: powershell, remote-execution

We have a program running on about 400 PCs (All W7). This program is called Wisa.

We receive regular updates for this program, named something like `wisa_update1.0.exe`, `wisa_update1.1.exe`, `wisa_update2.0.exe`, etc. The users can not do the update themself due to account restrictions.

We manage to do the update once and distribute it with a copy-item to all PCs. Then with `Enter-PSSession` I can go to each PC and update the program with the following command:

```
wisa_update3.0 /verysilent
```

(with the argument `/verysilent` no questions are asked)

This is already a major gain in time, but I want to do the update more automatically.

I have a file "pc.txt" with all 400 PCs in it. I use this file already for the `Copy-Item` via `Get-Content`. Now I want to use this file to do the updates with the above command, but I can't find a good way to use a remote executable with a parameter in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is load `get-content -Path $PClist` and then run your script actions in a `foreach`.  You'll want to adapt this example to your own script:

```
$PClist = 'c:\pc.txt'

$aComputers = Get-Content -Path $PClist

foreach ($Computer in $aComputers)
{ 
code actions to perform 
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. But i think i did not well explained the question. It's that, were you wrote 'code actions to perform' that i miss. How to perform the command: e:\wisa_update3.0 /verysilent
This command is on every pc and i want to start it from a management station.

Comment: @user2181342 In that section is where you create your `PSSession` and then `Enter-PSSession` and finally, execute your update.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use multithreading and get it over with fraction of time (provided you have a good machine). The below mentioned link explains how to do it well.

http://www.get-blog.com/?p=22